# Require/Include in php

Tags: php, file, require, classnotfound

I need some help, I have 2 php files and when I am calling some functions it tells me that

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_contents() in /home/f77inq/public_html/php/shares.php on line 13**

eventhough in the files from where I call the functions I have typed require("name ofmy file");

**shares.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'> 
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> 
<title>Shares</title> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' /> 
</head> 

<body> 
adad
<?php

    $data = get_contents();
    print_contents($data);
?>
</body> 

</html>
```

This is the file from where I am calling the functions.

```
    <?php

require("../../php_include/services.php");
require("../../php_include/query.php");


putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1");


function get_contents() {

    $conn = db_connect();
    $shares = get_share($conn);
    db_disconnect($conn);
    $contents = array('shares' => $shares);
    return $contents;
}


function print_contents($contents) {
    ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Rate</th>

            </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($contents['shares'] as $share) {
        print "<tr>";

    //****** LINKS TO EVERY
        $identifier = urlencode($share['COMPANY']);
        print "<td><a href='share-details.php?company={$identifier}'>{$share['COMPANY']}</a></td>";

        print "<td>{$share['RATE']}</td>";

        print "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
        </table>
    <?php
}
require ("shares.php");            //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
?>
```

As you can see down bellow I require the shares php file.

**Both files are located in the same folder**

Comment: did you include the php file in your share.php file??

Comment: This seems backwards. Usually you put the functions in the script that you load with `require` in the script that calls the functions.

Comment: @habibulhaq He's doing it tht other way around: the script that defines the functions includes `share.php`. Go to the end of the second script.

Comment: oh i just saw the line..

Comment: I need to do like this, because I have other file that has the same functions (I need them to get more details from dataBase), If I put like include in share file then it will get only the specific functions and it wont work, or it will tell me that I have the same functions in 2 files.

Comment: The label for your code sample says "Share.php" but your code says "shares.php". Is your code label a typo, or is your require statement trying to refer to the wrong file name?

Comment: Are you using namespaces? If you're using a namespace the function will only be available within that namespace: http://3v4l.org/YoAQR

Comment: @Bobulous it's a typo sorry, fixed

Comment: @KorvinSzanto nope I am not using anykind of namespaces as you can see from the code.

Comment: @Nico12345 I would put a debug_backtrace in there, so you must be loading this file somewhere else to receive this error. I'd add a debug_backtrace to it to be sure.

Comment: are you tried calling the function like this way- `$this->get_contents()`?

Comment: @KhairulIslam that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KhairulIslam this gives me this. Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context i

Comment: i think you need to redefine the way this script work. If you need to do this strange things was definitely faulty.

Comment: @Nico12345, the code you have here is absolutely valid and works just fine. There is something else happening that you are unaware of, run `debug_print_backtrace()` in the top of the file and see where it's being loaded.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto to share.php or to the other file?

Comment: To the file that contains the error, view my answer.

Comment: Does the user running the web server has access to these files ?

Comment: @LucM hmm that's a good point, I am going to check

Comment: @LucM I checked and I have access :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for testing i put this code in a file named like.php-

```
<?php
function get_contents() {
        echo "Got it";
}
require ("shares.php");
?>
```

and in the shares.php file i used this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'> 
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> 
<title>Shares</title> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' /> 
</head> 

<body> 
<?php

    $data = get_contents();
     echo $data;
?>
</body> 

</html>
```

it works perfectly without eny error.

Comment: To me it's still this freaking error ((

Comment: @Nico12345, you need to figure out how to give us the REAL code that is erroring. This code is not invalid.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto I have done the same as Khairul did and I got the same issue.

Comment: He doesn't know what he's talking about. His suggestion made no sense.

Comment: wait, wait @Nico12345 let us know in the browser what url your are running. it is something like `localhost/like.php` or `localhost/shares.php` ?

Comment: @KorvinSzanto if I add require("share-company-links.php") to the share.php  it will give this error   

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_contents() (previously declared in /home/f77inq/public_html/php/share-company-links.php:12) in /home/f77inq/public_html/php/share-company-links.php on line 17**

Which means that the require("share.php") is called.

Comment: @KhairulIslam no I am working on a server which is not mine. 
[Click HERE](http://rapid.eik.bme.hu/~f77inq/php/shares.php)

Comment: that's i am assuming. man you should call your second script file not the shares.php like- `http://rapid.eik.bme.hu/~f77inq/php/links.php` not this one `http://rapid.eik.bme.hu/~f77inq/php/shares.php`

Comment: @KhairulIslam no no no, I am logged to the dataBase as an User and I have my own folder with my files, I edit them internally, if the files are in the same folder I just have to call them like I do, if they are in other folders then I call them other way, but not the way you showed.

Comment: @Nico12345, you need to make sure that that function is defined before you call it. If you are only loading the `shares.php` file, that function will never be available since you aren't defining it.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto is there a way to check ?

Comment: You can use `function_exists` to check if the function is there, if you don't know then you need to do a little more research on the standard organization of a php application.

Answer (score 0):

The error you show is from a file `shares.php`, yet the file you `require` is `share.php`. This error is likely happening somewhere else in the process since all of the code you've shown is valid and certainly works.

Comment: It's actually shares, i typo again )). It looks like it's something with the dataBase or I don't know, since I am doing it right(

Comment: @Nico12345 the error you pasted shows "shares.php", this cannot be caused by a database issue or anything like that. You are not providing the correct information.